# Making an installer using Inno which produce .rsrc extension file after installation

Tags: inno-setup

I have made an installer through inno setup , but when i installs it in my system on successful installation it gets installed in my programs folder showing all class files and properties file which can be easily decrypted. So i want to make it secure.I have seen other installed files they all are store with .rsrc format.Can anyone help regarding this?

Comment: Should you rather deploy .jar files?

Comment: Inno just installs files.  If you want to repack in a different format (such as jar or something else), you have to do that beforehand.

Comment: Can you please suggest which can convert it in .rsrc format?I am registring custom url protocol through inno then packing it.